# How to limit a specific area in order to have a topographic 3D map using MatLab?

Tags: coordinates, matlab, topography, dem, 3d-map

I am using `MatLab`, I want to build a topographic 3D map, I am following this [guide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/draping-data-on-elevation-maps.html#f19-22120), I have been doing the steps listed on the section **Draping Geoid Heights over Topography**, and I do not have any trouble getting the expected result, it looks like this.

[image: I have this]

Now, my trouble is that I want to have a specific area, just a country not the whole world... How can I limit a specific area using coordinates in order to have a topographic 3D map that looks like this one.

[image: expected result]

---